# Checking for duplicate records

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

So I have a following system and want to check if `joe` is following `joe`, the usernames are unique. So I basically want to prevent the user from following themselves. Here's what I have right now

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){
    $result1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username AND follow_to = :username");
    $result1->bindParam(':username', $follower);
    $result1->bindParam(':post_id', $username);
    $result1->execute();
    $reprint1 = $result1->rowCount();
}

if($reprint1 == 1){
    echo 'Error';
    exit();
}

elseif($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true && $reprint1 == 0){
    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username AND follow_to = :post_id");
    $result->bindParam(':username', $follower);
    $result->bindParam(':post_id', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $reprint = $result->rowCount();
}
print_r($reprint);

if($result->rowCount() < 1){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO followers (follow_from, follow_to) VALUES (:ff, :ft)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':ff', $follower, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ft', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else{
    echo 'Error';
    exit();
}
```

The issue with this is it returns the error *after* insert `joe` and `joe` into the database. So how would I prevent that from happening?

This is what is currently in my DB

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| id  | follow_from | follow_to |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| 256 | joe       | joe         |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Why not check ,if both follow_from and follow_to same before inserting the data into the database ?

Comment: What does it mean "*returns the error*"? And why do you use `username` not `user_id`?

Comment: So like `SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username AND follow_to = :post_id AND follow_to != follow_to`? @Golu

Comment: It returns `Error`, which means its pass through and hits the else statement. Why not use `username`? @Vyktor

Comment: So both statements are executed? Or do I get it wrong? And on the IDs: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you weren't using MySQL, you would just add a `check` constraint to the table:

```
check (following_from <> following_to)
```

Alas, MySQL supports the syntax, but doesn't do anything.  Most other databases support `check` constraints.

That leaves you with two choices.  The first is to check in php that `$follower != $username`.  When they are equal, generate an error or do what you want.  When they are not equal, then insert the row.

You can also enforce this in the database by using a before insert trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would  question your database model here. From what I gather, essentially you have Users, who can follow other Users, and you'd like to track which Users are following which other Users, and at the same time, of course, ensure that Users can't follow themselves.

If this model is correct, this is a many-to-many self referencing relationship. Off the top of my head, a User table, and a User-Relationship table could work here. For every 'connection', a new row in the User-Relationship table is created, specifying the User.id of both Users, and thus connecting them.

User-Relationship table:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| id  | follower_id | following_id      |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1   | 1           | 2                 |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| 2   | 2           | 1                 |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| 3   | 2           | 3                 |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
```

In the above example, Users 1 and 2 are both following each other, but User 2 is also following User 3, who isn't following anyone